# How to force one layer to stay attached to another layer when moving feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis

QGIS 2.18.13
Layer one) Sewer Main  [Layer Type: "MultiLineStringZ"]
Layer two) Sewer Lateral [Layer Type: "LineString"]

When moving the Sewer Main, the sewer laterals do not move with the main.  Instead, the user has to go back to each lateral and manually snap the sewer lateral node to the sewer main.

How can I force the lateral layer to stay attached to the main layer when moving the main layer?

Below I have tried to show a simple example of our project.  When the main is moved, it leaves behind the lateral (as shown in the Not Corrected example).  We are then forced to manually snap every lateral to the main (as shown in the Corrected example).

[image: Example of sewer main and sewer lateral layers not connected after moving the main layer]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QAD plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) that gives you the ability to move two layers simultaneously if you selected them, and stay connected (snapped) with each other.

Here is how it works:

- Enable editing mode of both layers
- Use `Move tool` from QAD plugin

[image]

- Select which lines you want to move
- Select the first line from the first layer, and hold `SHIFT` on your keyboard to select the second line from the second layer
- After selecting both lines, click on the right-click of your mouse button to finish selection
- Select the starting reference point on which the displacement will start

[image]

- Select the destination point of the target location of your lines

[image]

- Save edits

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, QGIS implements OGC Simple Feature, which is a spagetti model (not a topological).

I guess you can't do it in QGIS.